# UAT Website not working in Microsft Edge browser

Tags: web, testing, microsoft-edge

I have a UAT website, which is hosted in the client's domain. Soon all other browsers its working fine, but when I try that to open into Microsoft edge it gives me an error.
I already tried below steps

1. I cleared all history, cache, cookies, etc.
2. I have also updated the allow sites from internet options->security->Trusted Sites. And in that, I have added UAT website address, still no luck.

Error
"Can't reach this page".
Is it a network issue or a Microsoft edge issue?
If anyone knows the resolution on this then kindly let me know.

Edge browser Version - 44.17763

Comment: whether this web site only not working in Microsoft Edge browser? Please try to use IE Browser or Chrome to test your code.Also, try to use F12 developer NetWork tools to check the HttpRequest.

Comment: I am tester so client asked to test it on edge only. I checked on other browsers its working fine

Comment: When using F12 developer tools to debug the web site, whether it contains some error? Also, you could check the HTTP return status.

Comment: I checked that already with the help of developer. It shows 200. status ok

Answer (score 0):

> Error "Can't reach this page"

It's possible that Microsoft Edge application is corrupted causing this issue to occur. As an initial troubleshooting, run the [Windows App Troubleshooter](http://aka.ms/diag_apps10).

If the issue still persist, perform the following steps below:

- **Restart your PC**

  Restart your PC and then reopen Microsoft Edge. Select the **Start** button, then select **Power  > Restart**.
- **Install the latest updates**

  Run Windows Update to help correct problems by replacing outdated files, updating drivers, and fixing vulnerabilities.

  To check for updates, select the **Start button > Settings > Update & security  > Windows Update**, and then select **Check for updates**. If Windows Update says your PC is current, you have all the current updates.
- **Clear browsing history**

  Your browser automatically saves temporary Internet files to help pages load faster. Clearing this cache will sometimes fix page display problems.

  If you can open Microsoft Edge, select **Hub > History > Clear all history**. Select Browsing history and Cached data and files, and then select **Clear**.
- **Clear all browsing data**

  If you can open Microsoft Edge, select **Hub > History > Clear all history**. Select all the boxes, and then select **Clear**.
- **Repair or reset Microsoft Edge**

  Repairing the browser won't affect anything, but resetting will remove your history, cookies, and any settings you might have changed. You'll find these options in **Settings > Apps > Microsoft Edge > Advanced options > Repair**. Open Microsoft Edge then check if you can open any websites. If the issue persists, go to **Settings > Apps > Microsoft Edge > Advanced options > Reset**.

Besides, you could also check [this article](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/fix-cant-reach-page-error-microsoft-edge).